# Drawing arcs in AutoCAD?

Tags: autocad

I wish to draw a shape that looks like the following shape:

[image]

I have very exact widths of each of the arcs in mind, and a constant spacing between the arcs.

How can I draw this in AutoCAD?

Answer (score 1):

What i am thinking is that say the inner most are has a radius of 100.  the outter are will have a radius of 134.

Does that make sense.  so you know the radius of the arcs and the start points.  So use the arc command 2 points and radius to draw.  if you knew your end point it would be good.

otherwise you could draw a L shaped line on 134 by 134 and use it as your outer most limits of your circle.

I cheated and drew circles with the calculated radius and then drew the l and then clipped.